# Can we send push notification payload with plain text (No JSON)?

Tags: ios, json, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, payload

I am trying to figure out if we can send push notification payload as plain text like "This is notification text" not as json {aps: {alert:"notification"}}.

I know apple say in its documentation that you need to send json format payload and its also says you can add custom values. But what will happen if server send only plain text to APN server or how iOS or app will behave?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wrote yourself, this is not possible. If you will try to send a plain text to the APNS, **the notification won't arrive to the device at all.**

Comment: Or may be notification will arrive and iOS will search for dictionary (key: aps) if not found will not do anything.

Comment: It doesn't really matter, because you won't get any indication / callback / delegate that the notification has arrived, and you won't be able to do anything with it. BUT - I'm pretty sure that the notification won't even be delivered to the device.

Comment: Yeah, got it. Just want some light on this. Do you mean APN server or device OS will reject the payload because the payload is not JSON?

Comment: APNS server will reject it